# Find Root Struts 1.2 Web.xml URL-Pattern

Tags: java, struts, web.xml

This is a very simple question but causing some trouble.

I came onto this project and there aren't many people familiar with it left. I have the following in my web.xml file.

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>XSS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.lmig.acu.servletinits.CrossScriptingFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>XSS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

My question, is there a file somewhere located related to the web.xml that outlines where /* would be pointing to in the url-pattern above?

Comment: `/*` means "all urls". Every time the user hits a url of your application would pass from that filter

Answer (score 0):

(**/***) maps all URL paths to the Filter class `com.lmig.acu.servletinits.CrossScriptingFilter`.

Syntax for servlet mapping as per **servlet specification SRV.11.2**:

- A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix
  is used for path mapping.
- A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension
  mapping.
- A string containing only the ‘/’ character indicates the “default”
  servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
  request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.